# How to highlight the area on map that has more data points?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, arcgis-js-api

I am using ArcGIS Javascript API to display a base map and add data points to it. Now, I need to somehow highlight the area (say a city) or its border that has more data points. Alternatively, I want to color the data points differently based on their population in different areas. Looking at the ArcGIS API documentation, there seems nothing related to this. Any guidance on how it can be achieved is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve it by implementing **Choropleth** map API's offered by [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/)/[Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/).
[Telerik](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/choroplethhowtosetupachoroplethwithcsvandshapefile) also has control for the same.